# How to get Karma to run tests of a specific angular 6 component library inside workspace

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I have an angular 6 workspace (called miami-space) and have created a component library called "vice-lib". This directory tree looks like this:

```
.
└── miami-space       <-- This is my workspace directory
    ├── e2e
    │   └── src
    ├── node_modules
    ...
    ├── projects      <-- Projects directory for created libraries
    │   └── vice-lib
    │       └── src
    │           └── lib
    └── src           <-- The source directory for the app
        ├── app
        ├── assets
        └── environments
```

(I created the library with ng new library vice-lib --ext=vlib)

If I go to the root dir (miami-space) and run the unit tests with

> npm run test

Karma runs the tests in the browser, but because there are tests for the app and tests for the library, karma runs the tests in 2 phases.

The first phase *ONLY* runs the tests for the app and you see this in the console:

```
λ ~/dev/tasks/t-122/cat/miami-space/ npm run test

> miami-fake-app@0.0.0 test /Users/Plastikfan/dev/tasks/t-122/cat/miami-space
> ng test

 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active(node:41963) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
21 06 2018 13:47:36.106:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
21 06 2018 13:47:36.111:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
21 06 2018 13:47:36.111:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
21 06 2018 13:47:36.116:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
21 06 2018 13:47:39.894:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/    
21 06 2018 13:47:40.006:INFO [Chrome 67.0.3396 (Mac OS X 10.13.4)]: Connected on socket _5z2mq2NuMiHHahdAAAA with id 8795036
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Mac OS X 10.13.4): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.154 secs / 0.138 secs)
```

... and the test results for the app show up in the browser

If you hit <*CTRL*>-C, Karma kills the browser and then runs the tests for the library ONLY (*note the ^C denoting when I hit CTRL-C*):

```
^C  0% compiling21 06 2018 13:50:21.034:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
21 06 2018 13:50:21.035:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
21 06 2018 13:50:21.035:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
21 06 2018 13:50:21.044:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
21 06 2018 13:50:24.453:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/  
21 06 2018 13:50:24.544:INFO [Chrome 67.0.3396 (Mac OS X 10.13.4)]: Connected on socket FelqTteskkryAtnYAAAB with id 63644171
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Mac OS X 10.13.4): Executed 5 of 5 SUCCESS (0.112 secs / 0.093 secs)
```

So I don't really understand how Karma is running here, presuming this is intended behaviour.

Are you only allowed to run tests for the component library after running the application tests? What if I have a lot of tests in the app but I only want to run the library tests?

If I "cd" to the vice-lib directory and try to run the tests using npm run test, then because the package.json is a cutdown config which doesn't include a scripts section, npm fails understandably:

> echo 'Error: no test specified'

So I read up further on the karma documentation and saw the 'basePath' (by default set to empty string). This is described as:

> *The root path location that will be used to resolve all relative paths defined in files and exclude. If the basePath configuration is a
>   relative path, then it will be resolved to the __dirname of the
>   configuration file.*

I thought I could update this to point to the root of the library (hopefully with the option of specifying on the command line, so I could write multiple script entries, see further down below) ie

> ./src/projects/vice-lib

But this seems to have no effect on the behaviour of Karma and again both sets of tests are run, with a CTRL-C required to get to the 2nd phase running the library tests. This seems to be a very cumbersome workflow and I hope there is a way round this, so I can just run the library tests straight away.

Let's say I inserted another library into the workspace, so now there are 2 component libraries and an app. Does that mean I would have to run first the app tests, then vice-lib tests, then the new library tests? I think you can see where I'm going with this and it just doesn't seem to be right, unless I'm doing something wrong (most likely!).

I have a default test.ts file which is unchanged from the default which includes the line (for finding the test cases to run):

```
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

but I'm not sure how I could change this on a per library level.

I was hoping that I could define multiple entries in package.json: scripts, something like:

```
"test:app": "ng test",
"test:vice": "ng test --<some option to refer to .projects/vice-lib>"
```

so that I could directly run the tests for the library I want.

So how is Karma running here, and is it not designed to work with multiple projects in a workspace?

UPDATE: I also tried to use *fdescribe* on one of teh vice-lib test fixtures, but this had no effect other than a warning on the console:

> Chrome 67.0.3396 (Mac OS X 10.13.4) ERROR: 'DEPRECATION: fit and
>   fdescribe will cause your suite to report an 'incomplete' status in
>   Jasmine 3.0'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you need to run only tests for the library, you can use `ng test library-name`, like you use a build command to generate the dist files. Is explained [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library).

Comment: If all you ever want to run is the tests from the library (for example, if your app is simply a demo of the library and has no tests) an option is to remove the "test" section from the app, but keep the one for the library.